# Finding common elements between two arrays without any loop

Tags: ruby

I have two arrays say

```
arr1=[1,2,3,4,5]
arr2=[3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

and I have to find all common elements in both the arrays. Is it possible to find all common elements without any loop?

Comment: Is it a home assignment?

Comment: No my dear friend i have to implement some logic in my project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply write

```
arr1 & arr2
```

and you will get

```
=> [3, 4, 5]

irb(main):001:0> arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
irb(main):002:0> arr2 = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
=> [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
irb(main):003:0> arr1&arr2
=> [3, 4, 5]
irb(main):004:0
```

Comment: What is the purpose of posting another answer nine minutes after three same answers (one of which deleted) have already been posted?

Answer (score 3):

```
arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
arr2 = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

arr1 & arr2 # => [3, 4, 5]
```

But there's still a hidden loop in the implementation of [Array#&](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-26).

Comment: Yes, javascript doesn't have such convenient array intersection operator. Question is about ruby, though.

Comment: hum i have no earthly idea how I ended up here totally thought this was node.js question -_-

Answer (score 2):

Array [intersection](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-26)!

```
arr1 & arr2
#=> [3,4,5]
```